# Number of attempts needed to open lock

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

There are $3$ knobs for a lock $A,B,C$. Each can take $8$ positions, and for each knob there is one correct position. When $2$ of the knobs are at their correct positions, the knob opens (irrespective of the third). So the number of attempts to get it right will be $8^2=64$. Can you do better than that?

Comment: How did you arrive at 64?

Comment: @MonK: picking a random pair and trying all $64$ combinations for that pair.

Comment: Computer search gave this $48$-attempt solution: `[[2,7,2],[7,8,2],[6,4,3],[3,5,6],[2,3,4],[4,1,2],[4,4,7],[6,5,1],[7,5,7],[8,4,4],[8,3,5],[3,4,8],[1,2,6],[5,2,3],[1,1,4],[5,3,6],[8,8,1],[4,7,5],[1,8,3],[1,4,5],[7,2,4],[4,5,3],[7,7,3],[6,7,7],[5,6,4],[1,3,7],[6,3,2],[6,2,8],[7,6,6],[5,7,8],[2,1,5],[3,2,7],[6,8,5],[2,6,8],[8,1,6],[5,1,7],[5,5,2],[3,8,4],[1,7,1],[8,6,2],[3,6,1],[7,4,1],[2,8,6],[7,1,8],[3,3,3],[4,2,1],[4,8,8],[8,5,8]]` (I'm not sure if it's best possible.)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: How did you search?

Comment: By recursively picking a random combination from the remaining possible "correct" positions.  (Then repeating it a lot of times.)  It wasn't a too intelligent process, and it's not a particularly enlightening result.

Comment: It seems like we might be able to do an exhaustive search for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a 57-guess solution.

Let the knob positions come from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.  Try this strategy:  Make the following guesses:

$000,001,002,003,004,005,006,007$. (8 guesses)

If none of these are right, you can say that neither knob A nor knob B gets a $0$ (otherwise one would have combined with C to open the lock at some point).

Continue by guessing:

$110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117$.  (8 guesses)

If none of these are correct, you can say that neither knob A nor knob B gets a $1$.

Continue in this manner.  ($22x; 33x; ...$). (8 guesses each)

If you get to $667$ and still haven't opened the lock, then knobs A and B must both be $7$.

You've used 56 guesses so far.  So on your 57th try you open the lock with $77x$.

Comment: Good strategy from a human viewpoint, although demonstrably not the best one in this case (see @RebeccaJ.Stones's comment). With $3$ knobs and $8$ settings, this strategy is not a big improvement over sticking to $2$ of the knobs, but it would interesting to consider a more general problem and see how this strategy scales up against the more naive approach: $k$ settings per knob, $m$ knobs and we must get $1\leq n \leq m$ out of them right.

Comment: I think this is an impproved 32-guess solution: 000, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777; 012, 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 670, 701; 024, 135, 246, 357, 460, 571, 602, 713; 036, 047, 250, 361, 472, 503, 614, 725.  (In the first grouping, $x,x,x \pmod{8}$; in the second grouping $x, x+1, x+2 \pmod{8}$, etc.  The grouping after the ones I've shown would start $040$, but the AC combo of 0-0 has already been tried.  Other later possibilities are similar.

Comment: @paw88789: Now, if the right combination had been $053$, none of your 32 guesses would have opened the lock.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Frunobulax Yup, I think you're right.  I was too hasty!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{64}2$ is the expected number of attempts to find the correct combination when moving only two knobs at random.

Every time move two knobs to the same random setting.  The chance that at least one of them is correct is: $1-(\frac {7} {8})^2 = \frac {15} {64}$.  Move the other knob independently to a random setting.  The chance that both one of the two and the other nob is correct is: $\frac{15}{512}$.  The expected number of attempts until that happens is:$$\frac{512}{2\times 15}=17.0\dot{6}$$

Or move all of them independently to random settings.  The probability of at least two being correct is: ${3\choose 2}\frac{7}{8^3}+\frac{1}{8^3} = \frac {11}{256}$, so the expected number of attempts is $$\frac {256}{2\times 11}=11.\dot{\overline{63}}$$

The best strategy is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with 38 attempts:

166 - 177 - 266 - 277 - 616 - 626 - 661 - 662 - 717 - 727 - 771 - 772 - 128 - 182 - 218 - 281 - 812 - 821 - 345 - 354 - 435 - 453 - 534 - 543 - 678 - 687 - 768 - 786 - 867 - 876 - 111 - 222 - 333 - 444 - 555 - 666 - 777 - 888